# BOOT_COMPLETED not calling BroadcastRecevier

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I've looked over several post on this site about `BOOT_COMPLETED`  not calling the `Broadcast Receiver`. I thought my problem was similar to this question [BroadcastReceiver not working after BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878816/broadcastreceiver-not-working-after-boot-completed)

However, I'm not trying to capture more than one `Intent` in one service. I just want the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action.

Can you look over my code and let me know where and how to fix it?

Here is the Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <!--
         The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
         to target higher versions.
    -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!--
     Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

     NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
           where PACKAGE is the application's package name.



    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- permission for network state -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.sqllite.SQLViews" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ScheduleView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ConventionView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.EventList.DataView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.EventList.EventDetails" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts.AlertView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts.AlertDetails" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts.AlarmsService"
            class="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts.AlarmsService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts.AlarmsService"
                    android:value="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts.AlarmsService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts.AlarmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--
          BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.




        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--
          Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
          handle received messages.

          By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
          application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.



        -->

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
package com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";

    Intent startServiceIntent;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmsService.class);
            context.startService(startServiceIntent);
            Log.d("TAG", "alarmBroadcastReceiver");

            System.out.println("alarm broadcast reciver...");

        }



    }

}
```

Service:

```
 package com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.Alerts;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AlarmsService extends Service {


       String tag="alerttService";
       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
           Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
       }

       public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Service command started.");
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }


       @Override
       public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
           super.onStart(intent, startId);

           Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
           Log.i(tag, "Service started. ..");
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }

}
```

Comment: Is it installed to the SDCard or internal? Have you tried setting `android:installLocation` to `internalOnly` on your `<manifest>` element?

Comment: Where are you testing this code (device/emulator? which OS version?)? Did you run your activity manually (e.g., via the launcher) before trying the reboot?

Comment: I'm testing this on the emulator. Min 8 , Target 16.

Comment: For some very strange reason, when I created a new emulator, I got it to work. however, it doesn't work in Honeycomeb or earlier device setting on the emulator

Comment: I also rebooted using adb....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using emulators that I created before I installed sdk for Jellybean. I created new Emulators for all the versions and  now the program it works in Android 8 and up on the emulator.